# Hibernate connection error Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting the following exception while fetching data from DB using hibernate in spring mvc.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/DemoApp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "this.serverVariables" is null
```

My chunk of code is below.

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  List<User> listUsr = session.createQuery("From User Where username=\'"+usr.getUsername()+"\' and passphare=\'"+usr.getPassphare()+"\'").list();
  
  System.out.println("Lit user "+listUsr);
 
  if(listUsr != null && listUsr.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Empty details");
  } else {
      System.out.println("Value fetched");
  }
```

Sevlet code ..

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url"
    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mycart?useSSL=false" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="PASWORD" />

</bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.demoapp.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
 </bean>
<!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
<bean id="myTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" /> 
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

POM snap example...

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.21.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.21.Final</version>
            </dependency>

    
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>



                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.26</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
    
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: is this issue solved? what is the solution for this problem please share with us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MySQL from Java: NullPointerException inside MySQL driver connection logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081527/cant-connect-to-mysql-from-java-nullpointerexception-inside-mysql-driver-conne)

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be driver issue. Please check version of driver and database version.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue and regardless of research and code additions I could not resolve the issue. I recommend using https://start.spring.io/ to recreate your project adding the Spring Web, Spring Data JPA, and MySQL Driver dependencies. I also recommend this video as it walks through a very simple connection to mysql https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8g9eNnFpHQ. This was helpful to me in making sure none of the code I had written was the issue. I can not find any obvious errors in your code but I hope this provides some resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997)
https://github.com/spullara/mysql-connector-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java

Upgrade connector , make sure you have latest version of mysql connector

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.18</version>
    </dependency>
```